# Convert image array to blob format and render with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I am tryins to convert an array of images in blob format and send to script php to process the data but the array of blobs is not sending correctly, i dont know why.
My input in html is this:

```
<div class="form-group">
<input id="imagen" onchange="send()" type="file" name="imgs" multiple="true" class="form-control required" >
</div>
```

And my script in javascript is this:

```
<script>
    var y='#imagen';
    var z;        
    var blobs;
    function send(){
        x=trans(y); 
        };

    function trans(v) {
        var file    = document.querySelector(v).files;

        for (i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
            var reader  = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file[i]);
            reader.onloadend = function () {
            blobs[i]=reader.result;
            }
        }
        console.log(blobs.length);

        }
</script>
```

I'm trying to send the array blob to script php throught ajax call:

```
var form = $('#for_addH')[0];
                var formData = new FormData(form);
                 formData.append("blobs",JSON.stringify(blobs));
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "phpfunc/posadas/nueva_habitacion.php",
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,
                cache:false,
                data: formData,
                timeout: 180000
            })
```

So, my problem is that the array is not sending correctly.  help please.

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating `data URI`s, not `Blob`s.

If requirement is actually to post a stringified array of concatenated `data URI`s, you can use an immediately invoked function expression. `FileReader` `loadend` event returns results asynchronously. You can pass `i` to an IIFE to retain `i` reference within `for` loop

```
function trans(v) {
    var file    = document.querySelector(v).files;

    for (i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
      (function(curr) {
        var reader  = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file[curr]);
        reader.onloadend = function () {
          blobs[curr]=reader.result;
        }
      })(i);
    }
    console.log(blobs.length);

}
```

Comment: This is returned by your suggestion: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined                     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Comment: Where is `send()` called? Why do you pass `form` to `FormData()` then call `.append()`? Are you trying to send a concatenated string of multiple `data URI`s to server?

Comment: in the image, by the event onchange ()

Comment: Yes, where is `send` defined at `javascript`? Can you create a stacksnippets or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: `blobs` is `undefined`. Define `blobs` as an array `var blobs = []` https://jsfiddle.net/w0q80t2q/1/

Comment: When `blobs.length` is equal to `file.length`, all files have been processed. It is not necessary to pass `form` to `FormData()` https://jsfiddle.net/w0q80t2q/2/

Comment: yes, but i need save the blobs in my bd, so, it is passed trougth ajax to my scrip php. Still not works my script :(

Comment: You are not passing `Blob` instances. You are passing `data URI`s. Can you include `php` at Question? Why do you not simply submit the `<form>` element? Though no `form` element appears at `javascript` at Question.

Comment: I do not submit because I need to save in the bd the data URI s.

Comment: @M.Doe What is "the bd"? Do you mean database? Instead of sending single string at one property of `FormData`, you can create a key for each `File` object converted to `data URI`. See also [Upload multiple image using AJAX, PHP and jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/), http://stackoverflow.com/a/42037165/